# Can a normal process be executed in VMX-Root mode?

Tags: linux, process, virtualization, kvm

I read kvm used hardware-assisted virtualization.

With VT-x, there are two modes :  VMX-Root and VMX-NonRoot. Each mode has four rings(0 to 3), is that correct?

On an Linux operating system with kvm, is the kernel run in VMX-root? what about processes in userspace? Are they in VMX-Root which means a userspace program can be used as hypervisor?

Answer (score -1):

As to the first question,yes,it's correct.As to the second one,all userspace processes run the ring 3,guest kernel in ring 0,which you can intercept the rdtsc instruction in guest vm userspace and  hanle the vm_exit in arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c to prove it using the vmx_getcpl().Of cause,a user space program has no way to become a hypervisor or be used as one.I cannot quite get why you ask this.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "intercept the rdtsc instruction", "handle the vm_exit...to prove it using the vmx_getcpl()". maybe my question is not clear so let's me reformulate : let's say we have run a VM with kvm. This VM is run in VMX-NonRoot (whatever if we run a userspace program or a kernel space code). Now let's look the host. it seems obvious that the kvm module run in VMX-Root and in host ring0. all other host kernel code run in ring0 but in VMX-Root mode or VMX-nonRoot mode? same things for userspace : in ring 3, ok, but on which mode?

Comment: I'm afraid you are not that clear about vmx-root and vmx-noroot.see here [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~412/lectures/L04_VTx.pptx).vmx-root and vmx-nonroot are the concepts that are only used to describe two states of Intel VT VMs and VMM,the VMs run in vmx-noroot mode and use vmx_exit to enter vmx-root mode,which is the level of VMM.Guest VM(including kernel and user space applications)run in VMX-nonroot mode and VMM run in VMX-root mode,is that clear.I hope the link will help you ,it's a PPT.